# How To Sort Array Based on Input Array

Tags: php, laravel

I have a page that allows a user to search for stories between date ranges.

The next page allows the user to select certain stories from that queried list and I would like to give the user the option to create a custom order for the stories to be displayed in on the next page.

This is how that second page looks

[image: page example]

How can I display the stories according to the "Order" values provided by the user on the next page?

Comment: By... sorting them based on the order value...!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change you inputs to this:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="selected[{{ $story->id }}]" id="selected" value="{{ $story->id }}">
<input type="text" name="order[{{ $story->id }}]" id="order">
```

Then your PHP code should be like this:

```
$oldStoryArray = Story::whereIn('id', $selections)->get();

$newStoryArray = array();

foreach($order as $storyIndex => $place){
    foreach($oldStoryArray as $story){
        if($story['id'] == $storyIndex){
            $newStoryArray[$place] = $story;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

This should work, please let me know if it doesn't

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Here is my code now: http://laravel.io/bin/Gqlwr . I tried your solution, although, I don't think it's functioning correctly. When I try to order it doesn't really sort them properly.

Comment: I'll look at it tomorrow and see what I can do

Comment: @cmill02s can I see your input fields? When I know what the look like it won't be too hard to write a short function which sorts them